Rails: Active Record Validation for has_one
I have 2 models
class A < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :b, dependent: :destroy
 has_one :c, dependent: :destroy
end

and
class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a
  validates :ip_address, presence_true, format : {with: regex,message:"must be valid"}
end

While saving / updating above records,
transaction do
  save_b(params)
  save_c(params)
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved => e
   handle_error
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
   handle_error
end

save_b(params)
 self.b ||= build_b(params)
 b.update!(params)
end

If invalid ip_address is sent in params, above code rescues in ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved block. How can I refactor so that error rescues in ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid and I get error message defined for ip_address in model B

I think that ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved could be caused because you are updating a relation from A, try, creating or updating the B record without the self.b.

I think you may be looking for validates_associated that would run the validations in the associated record and bail early with a validation error.

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid will be triggered if you use save! or create! then you can inspect b.errors
See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid.html
Instead of raising the exception you could do something like
if a.save
  redirect_to a
else
  render json: {errors: a.errors}


As everyone said above, when the update! method is called on b, if the validation fails, it doesn't throw ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid directly but rather bubbles up as ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved.
So, I suggest the following logic:
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :b, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :c, dependent: :destroy

  def save_b(params)
    self.b ||= build_b
    b.assign_attributes(params)
    
    if b.valid?
      b.save!
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(b)
    end
  end
end

By this way, validates the b record by using valid? and in case validation fails, it will throw ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
